# Two columns at the same group level Birt Report

Tags: sql, crosstab, birt

I am trying to develop a report that looks something in Birt along the lines of

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
               |                  Event Identifier                                  |
               ----------------------------------------------------------------------
               | Event Date  | Event instance #1| Event Instance 2| Event Instance 3| 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Employee Number| Event Date  | Entry            | Entry           | Entry           |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

My current problem is that the "Event Date" is actually simply the MAX(EventDate) for the Event Instance Date.

Individually I can get all of the information I need, however I cannot get it so that I can display the Event Date at the Overall Event level next to the Event Instance Level.

If I bring it up one level to be above the event instance, it will only display the information for the first patient that has a date for that event and it will

Is it possible to have two columns at the same group level within a Birt crosstab?

Quick Edit: A big problem with this, is that this is the general format that the customer I am writing this for wants it in. I tried to show them a vertically oriented version using a normal table but they weren't happy with the results.

Comment: Is birt also known as actuate?

Comment: A quick google search seems to tell me yes as far as I can tell.